# How do I map SSIS 2012 Package Variables to Parameters?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, environment-variables, ssis-expressions

I have created multiple packages that use variables to assign Connection Manager `Expressions` such as `Connection String`. However in the new SQL 2012 [Project Deployment Model](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx) I don't seem to be able to configure these variables.

Would I therefore need to create these `Parameters` for the `Environment` and map them to specific Package `Variables`? Is this even possible and how is this done?

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211591/845584) describes configuring the `Parameters`, but not associating to **package** `Variables`.

Further to this, it seems I *could* set a Varaiable `Expression` to be a Project or Package `Parameter`, however this seems a bit convoluted. Perhaps I should stop using `Variables` altogether?

[image]

---

Update: I've now cut-over to using Project-level and Package-level Parameters (instead of Package Variables) when I need to modify per-environment settings such as file paths and connection strings. Perhaps this was the intent from MS: any best practice advice is of course, still welcome.

Comment: have you refered to [Create environment, map it to project and package level parameters and assign reference to project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2013/10/08/ssis-2012-automation-part-2-create-environment-map-it-to-project-and-package-level-parameters-and-assign-reference-to-project.aspx) and [SSIS 2012 Deployment Model and Mapping SSIS Parameters to Environment Variables](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmpowerobjects/archive/2012/11/15/ssis-2012-deployment-model-and-mapping-ssis-parameters-to-environment-variables.aspx)

Comment: I had a look and it seems to be a terminology problem - "variables" in this sense are the new SSIS Catalog "environment variables", and not *package* variables. 

It seems now that you use Project-Level Parameters for Global (cross-package) shared settings which you can modify in the Catalog per environment, Package-Level Parameters for per-package settings you can also to modify per environment and then Package Variables for intra-package settings (like for-each loop file path) which don't change per environment.

Answer (score 1):

I am bit too late to answer this question but I would like to make a point about [Parameter role in package deployment model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213214.aspx)

It says'

> In general, if you are deploying a package using the package deployment model, you should use configurations instead of parameters.
>
> When you deploy a package that contains parameters using the package
>   deployment model and then execute the package, the parameters are not
>   called during execution. If the package contains package parameters
>   and expressions within the package use the parameters, the resulting
>   values are applied at runtime. If the package contains project
>   parameters, the package execution may fail.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206184/how-to-configure-ssis-2012-project-to-run-under-different-environment-configurat) is a beautiful answer about setting up variables for different environment configurations.

Comment: Very odd - can't say I've had that issue: "If the package contains project parameters, the package execution may fail."